# Intercept fling velocity by list item in Jetpack Compose LazyList

Tags: list, android-jetpack-compose, fling

I have a long list of items to display - text and images - think of a product page.
One of the items to display is a special one - component which should display a frame of a video based on a scroll offset (so it animates the image, mimcs the behavior of seeking a movie back and forth).

I have no problem with proper behavior when scrolling slowly through the list and then scrolling through the frames (as the touch input is on the image frames), but I have the issue with stopping the fling on the list when approaching the image (and moreover how to approach smooth velocity takeover).

Example - we have 30 items in the list, first 15 are text, 16th is this special animated image and the rest are also text.
Now from the beginning of the list we perform a strong fling - it should travel through the text items, display the image frames properly (with decreasing velocity) and then travel further to the other text items if the fling was strong enough.